# Ruby Object#id warnings and Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, warnings, rails-activerecord

We keep seeing warnings like the following when we run our specs:

> Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id

The code in question is accessing the id of an ActiveRecord model (which is an attribute on the table, obviously, rather than the object instance ID in the Ruby VM).

Does anyone know how to turn these particular warnings off or somehow avoid them?

Comment: If this is in a test, are you sure you're accessing a real active record  entity, and not a regular ruby object?

Comment: Ah ... these may well be mocked objects

Comment: You should answer the question, because that totally fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing mocking / stubbing (because you mentioned specs).

In my case, I run into these warnings when I stub an ActiveRecord object and access its ID attribute.

In cases where you expect to access the ID of your ActiveRecord object, I'd recommend you do the following:

```
 mock("MyActiveRecordObject", :id => 1001)
```

Answer (score 15):

Try using `[:id]` instead of `.id`

Comment: Because there was a user who was being malicious and downvoting my everything.

Answer (score 10):

When an object is descended from `ActiveRecord::Base`, a call to `id` goes to AR::B's `id` method rather than the deprecated one on `Object`.

That warning usually means one of my objects isn't what I think it is.

Answer (score 4):

Your object is not actually an AR object, usually indicating that some data retrieval has failed (`Table.find_by_name('nonexistent name')` will return `nil`).  If all you want to do is shut off the visible warnings, you can turn off `whiny_nils` in your config, otherwise do an `is_a?` test before trying to access the object's attributes and handle the failure case gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

The object#id warning only happen on regular ruby classes like NilClass. ActiveRecord::Base overrides object#id