# Rails Active Record ID vs. Object ID + Active::Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, object

I've been receiving messages like this:

warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id

I read and attempted the tricks from [Ruby Object#id warnings and Active Record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608713/ruby-objectid-warnings-and-active-record) without success:

```
108-125-94-123:toptickets johnnygoodman$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.0.3)
>> ticket_id = 8899
=> 8899
>> ticket = Ticket.where(:number => ticket_id)
=> [#<Ticket id: 97, name: "Set Up API to Feed Customer Info into Bronto  ", number: "8899", category_id: 15, created_at: "2011-01-31 21:24:29", updated_at: "2011-01-31 21:24:29", position: 20>]
>> ticket.id
(irb):3: warning: Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id
=> 2175680980
>> ticket[:id]
TypeError: Symbol as array index
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:363:in `[]'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:363:in `send'
        from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.0.3/lib/active_record/relation.rb:363:in `method_missing'
        from (irb):4
>> ticket.class
=> ActiveRecord::Relation
```

I'd expect that when I queried for ticket it would be of class ActiveRecord::Base. I'm not sure what to do to get that going or if its the direction I should head in.

Goal: Query for a ticket, print its id. In the example above, the id's value should be 97.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ticket = Ticket.where(:number => ticket_id)` returns an ActiveRecord::Relation (which when evaluated in IRB, performs the database query and returns an array of tickets). So `ticket.id` is trying to perform `.id` on the entire array of tickets, not one actual ticket.

Maybe you only want the first result?

```
>> ticket = Ticket.where(:number => ticket_id).first
>> puts ticket.id
=> 97
```